# Create class by inheriting from QTreeView

Tags: qt, inheritance, qtreeview

I am starting a project using Qt. I am trying two approaches to get a View to do some of the following. This question involves the approach of inheriting from QTreeView.

I like what QTreeView does. I just want some added features.

First, what I want is to make a hierarchy tree view that will allow me to see categories containing other categories, the further right the columns go the more specific they are until it gets to the most specific. The metrics are shown on the row containing the most specific column. The view rows containing each generalized column will be bold and contain a summary of each metric, calculated by the model (or view?). The metrics will be in the model on each row in terms of the most specific column.

For example, consider a model with the following data (the last 3 columns containing numbers):

Country|Province-State|County-Parish|City-Town|Population|PerCapitaIncome|WalMarts

So my view would look similar to this:

```
Country Province-State County-Parish City-Town Population PerCapitaIncome Walmarts
+ USA                                           250000000           42000     2354
        + Alabama                                 9000000           23000      153
                       + Barbour                    15324           19032        1
                                     Eufaula         6520           23000        1
        + Tennessee                              14000000           29000      299
                       + Hamilton                   70000           41000        4
                                     East Ridge     23000           32000        2
```

Second, I need it to work with QSqlTableModel. I have seen it show the model before, but it doesn't have any way to create the rows by a heirarchy, similar to above. That was going to be my second modification.

The third reason is bold headers are only an option if you have the sort turned on via:

```
 view->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

When sort is on, the bold headers only works for the higher-up rows and then turns off on lower ones. I want to fix that bug.

The QTreeView::drawRow virtual method looks to be all I need to override to accomplish the first challenge (and perhaps the third). The second challenge dealing with QSqlTableModel, I'm not so sure about.

Anyhow, I built a simple class inheriting from QTreeView with a generic ctor and dtor that just calls the QTreeView methods. As for drawRow, however, I ran into the following problem. The QTreeView::drawRow function starts out like this:

```
QTreeView::drawRow(
    QPainter *painter,
    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
    const QModelIndex &index) const {

  Q_D(const QTreeView);
  QStyleOptionViewItemV4 opt = option;
  const QPoint offset = d->scrollDelayOffset;
  const int y = option.rect.y() + offset.y();
  const QModelIndex parent = index.parent();
  const QHeaderView *header = d->header;
  const QModelIndex current = currentIndex();
  const QModelIndex hover = d->hover;
  const bool reverse = isRightToLeft();
  const QStyle::State state = opt.state;
  const bool spanning = d->spanning;
  const int left = (spanning ? header->visualIndex(0) : d->leftAndRight.first);
  const int right = (spanning ? header->visualIndex(0) : d->leftAndRight.second);
  ...
```

The function relies on have Q_D(const QTreeView) run succesfully and return "d", an instance of the QTreeViewPrivate class which contains important info related to layout and the remainder of the function. Since I am inheriting into my CustomTreeView class, CustomTreeViewPrivate will have to be defined and instantiated first if I am to run Q_D(const QTreeView) in CustomTreeView::drawRow().

Is creating this private class really necessary to inherit and make significant changes? What is the benefit of inheriting here if all I can do is some perfunctory processes and then call the QTreeView::drawRow to do the actual drawing?

I want to change how its drawing.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to cover as much of your question as possible.  The big thing throughout all of your problems is that much of what you are trying to accomplish should be done through the model, not the view (such as having certain entries in bold).  Because of this, you will have to make your own model.  You can inherit a QSqlTableModel and alter things as you wish.  For example, if you want to bold certain items, in the data model, you could write

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const
{
    QVariant result = QSqlTableModel::data(index, role);
    // add your own qualifications to the following if statement, checking the row
    // and such
    if(role == Qt::FontRole) {
        QFont font = result.value<QFont>();
        font.setBold(true);
        return font;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The last thing you wrote was about Q_D.  This is only for use in the Qt source code.  If you are implementing your own paint function, you do not have to use this macro.

I would read up on [models](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemmodel.html) very heavily, you may need a lot of the stuff in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I would need a custom model class too, inherited from one of the SqlModel types. I got a working example up a few days ago using a loop and one QSqlQueryModel per "hierarchy" level, like "select Country, "", "", "", sum(Population), sum(PerCapita), sum(Walmarts)". I would add the results to QList<QStandardItem *>, then to a row in a QStandardItemModel. I would run another query within that loop that like "select "", "Province-State", "", "", sum(Population), sum(PerCapita), sum(Walmarts)", etc. I then created a QTreeView and attached the QStandardItemModel to that.

Comment: The above works, but there isn't a good way for me to push changes to the view back to the database table. Therefore, I was looking at inheriting QViewTree to make it work better with QSqlTableModel (currently, it isn't designed to work with classes inherited from QAbstractTableModel [link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstracttablemodel.html#details). Thanks for the suggestion. I think I can accomplish something with my original setup using a QSqlTableModel to do updates. I will consider this. I still wonder why I cannot get QTreeView to draw any different.